# Remove/replace a systemd unit requirement via drop-in

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to replace a requirement of a systemd unit? The requirement for this is where I have a systemd unit for a service that `Requires=docker.service` but I want it to instead require `early-docker.service`.

I know it is possible to do a similar thing with `ExecStart` where you can put an `ExecStart=` in to clear the unit's value but doing similar does not seem to work for requirements.

As an alternative, can the `Requires` predicate include an environment variable which would be overridable via drop-in to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies cannot be removed by drop-ins unfortunately. You need to put modified unit: [upstream documentation](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/250e9fadbcc0ca90e697d7efb40855b054ed3b8f/man/systemd.unit.xml#L1786).